# Linux shell to windows batch file

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file

I have a Windows dedicated server and I installed Multicraft to run Minecraft servers, and I wanted to add a accept EULA button, since I did not know much about bat files, so I found a sh file online and I did not want to use Cygwin because I don't know how to install it and make it run properly.
I want to change this to a .bat file:

```
#!/bin/sh echo 'eula=true' > "$SERVER_DIR/eula.txt"
```

it basically finds the line eula=false in eula.txt and changes it to true from what i understand

Comment: That's not what that line does at all. That line creates a file called eula.txt in the directory represented by the `$SERVER_DIR` variable and puts the line `eula=true` in it. If any text exists in eula.txt already, that text is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that this is what you're looking for:

```
echo eula=true>>%SERVER_DIR%\eula.txt
```

Given the double greater-than symbol it should append the line to the indicated file.  Note that we're using a backslash here.  You might want to look at the contents of that SERVER_DIR environment variable to see if it will work on a Windows-based computer.

If you want to mirror the behavior in the UNIX script then use a single greater-than symbol to overwrite the file content.